# Pre save example

Tags: python, django

I've never used `pre_save` before and haven't found any good examples on it. I want to modify a field that shouldn't be empty. If given field already contains a value, nothing should happen.

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save

@receiver(pre_save, sender=Shows)
def shows_receiver(sender, **kwargs):
    #if writer kwarg is null don't override current data

class Poll(models.Model):
    director = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, )
    writer = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, )
```

Comment: Show us the error message you receive

Comment: @itsneo never mind it should be in the presave

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by modifying the instance passed to receiver:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Shows)
def shows_receiver(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.some_field == "":
        instance.some_field = "something"
```

Or by using [default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#default) value for the field in the model:

```
class Shows(models.Model):
    some_field = models.CharField(max_length=128, default="something")
```